# Ubuntu Clion CMake Error

Tags: 18.04, clion

I installed [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) but I am still now able to run my main `hello world` file.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oW58.png)

Here is the whole error, hope an experienced can recognize give and give a solution.

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434410/5790193).

Comment: Alright, Thank You :)